# Difference between self.driver and self.browser

Tags: python, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was going through Selenium with Python tutorials when I encountered this. I saw two different implementation, to call the Firefox instance.

The first method is this

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver=webdriver.Firefox()
```

The second method is like this

```
def setUp(self):
    self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Is there any fundamental difference in between these two implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just the name of variable and you can name it something else as well. Neither `self.browser` nor `self.driver` is defined in `unittest` class.  You can add a property dynamically to an object in Python. Its just a simple example of that.

Comment: I get it now. That was the silliest thing I could have asked. :(